# Access query converted to SSMS produces fewer results

Tags: sql, t-sql, ms-access, ssms

I am moving a data pull from Access to SSMS, but the results are not matching.  The Access query is:

```
INSERT INTO EVAL_CORE ( eval_id, status, published, user_id, quality_date, q_percent, max_q_score, tot_q_score, eform_id, hierarchy, last_rev_date, last_activity, evaluator_id )

SELECT dbo_evaluations.eval_id, dbo_evaluations.status, dbo_evaluations.published, dbo_evaluations.user_id, dbo_evaluations.quality_date, dbo_evaluations.q_percent, dbo_evaluations.max_q_score, dbo_evaluations.tot_q_score, dbo_evaluations.eform_id, dbo_evaluations.hierarchy, dbo_evaluations.last_rev_date, dbo_evaluations.last_activity, dbo_evaluations.evaluator_id

FROM FORMS_REF INNER JOIN dbo_evaluations ON FORMS_REF.eform_id = dbo_evaluations.eform_id

WHERE (((dbo_evaluations.status)=4 Or (dbo_evaluations.status)=5) AND ((dbo_evaluations.published)=1) AND ((dbo_evaluations.quality_date) Between [Forms]![FRM_DATA_PULL]![STRT_DATE] And [Forms]![FRM_DATA_PULL]![END_DATE]));
```

While the SQL query is:

```
INSERT INTO EVAL_CORE ( [eval_id]

, [status]

, [published]

, [user_id]

, [quality_date]

, [q_percent]

, [max_q_score]

, [tot_q_score]

, [eform_id]

, [hierarchy]

, [last_rev_date]

, [last_activity]

, [evaluator_id] )



SELECT [eval_id]

, [status]

, [published]

, [user_id]

, [quality_date]

, [q_percent]

, [max_q_score]

, [tot_q_score]

, qf.[eform_id]

, [hierarchy]

, [last_rev_date]

, [last_activity]

, [evaluator_id]



FROM [QFINITI].[Qfiniti_Platform].[dbo].[evaluations] qf

INNER JOIN FORMS_REF sr ON qf.eform_id = sr.[eform_id]

WHERE (((qf.[status])=4 Or (qf.[status])=5)

AND ((qf.[published])=1) AND ((qf.[quality_date])

BETWEEN @sdate AND @edate));
```

Access produces 3000+ records (which is expected) while the SQL query returns about 500, well below what it should be.  I don't see where the difference may be.

Comment: How are you getting @sdate AND @edate? What is your locale and what format are you using?

Comment: @Remou At the start of the script, I use 'Cast(CONVERT(varchar(10), Getdate()-1,101) as Datetime)' to set the '@sdate' and '@edate' variables.  The data that it does pull fits the date criteria, but it doesn't net as much as the Access Query which is odd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Access you are doing

```
FROM FORMS_REF INNER JOIN dbo_evaluations
```

In SQL you have it the opposite way around:

```
FROM [QFINITI].[Qfiniti_Platform].[dbo].[evaluations] qf INNER JOIN FORMS_REF
```

This probably shouldn't make a difference.

However it does open the question: SQL is querying from a Linked Server [QFINITY]. How like the Access database is the [QFINITY Platform] database on that server?

Comment: Both systems are using the [Qfiniti_platform].  SSMS is using linked server, while the Access database is linked to dbo tables on the same server.  They are querying the same table.  I can change the From clause as you suggested a see if that makes a difference.

Comment: It's worth trying, but I'm not sure that it will. The ON is pretty simple and should be bi-directional. The other thing to check is the definition of the Queries in Access which define the Linked table: they may be doing something odd. Similarly, in SSMS and in Access do a simple count(*) of each table separately: they should be equal. If they're not then something in Access is off: for a simple count SSMS should get that right.

Comment: I ran the count, and Access and SSMS match.  I also adjusted the FROM clause to check every possibility, and the result is the same.  I wonder if the OR in the WHERE is handled differently somehow.  I could change the '4 or 5' multi-part qualifier to >3 instead.  I don't know what other difference there could be.